# Why is Dataset upset by division by zero?

Tags: warning-messages, dataset

Consider this example:

```
ds = Dataset @ Transpose[<|"a" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, "b" -> {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}|>,
                         AllowedHeads -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now say I need to work with the ratios of these two values.  This works fine:

```
ds[;;-2, #a/#b &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this fails:

```
ds[All, #a/#b &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It would be easier for me to just get a result with some ComplexInfinities.  Does the operation fail by desgin or oversight?  Is there a workaround?  Should I just use

```
ds[All, Quiet[#a/#b] &]
```

all the time or is there a more general solution?  `Off[General::infy]` doesn't prevent this from failing, though the failure message can't be displayed properly.

Comment: I'd upvote this if it weren't deleted. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Undeleted because I just discovered `FailureAction`.

Comment: Post it! :-) ..

Answer (score 12):

One possible solution is using `Quiet`:

```
ds[All, Quiet[#a/#b]&]
```

Another possible solution is using the [`FailureAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html) option:

```
ds[All, #a/#b, FailureAction -> None]
```

Comment: Why CW?  Seems like a good self-answer to me. *shrug*

Comment: I'll delete this if someone writes a comprehensive answer.  Just collecting here what I find as I progress ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't want to discourage other answers.  I'm just learning to use `Dataset`.  I didn't need to use it before.  Now I have a good application.

Comment: I think `FailureAction` is your best option here.