# Why is Query so much slower than Part?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, core-language

Time for another of these<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54853/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55294/121)</sup> as yet another new-in-10 function appears to have poor performance compared to older alternatives.  This time: [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Query.html) appears to be orders of magnitude slower than [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) when used for simple extraction.

For example:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

x = RandomInteger[99, 1*^6];
spans = Span @@@ Partition[Sort @ RandomInteger[{1, 1*^6}, 5000], 2, 1];

Do[x[[s]], {s, spans}]      // AccurateTiming
Do[Query[s][x], {s, spans}] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.00447013
>
> 3.586205
> ```

Here `Query` is 800 times slower than `Part`.  I know that `Part` is well optimized for packed arrays.  Perhaps `Query` hasn't been similarly optimized yet.  Let's try unpackable data:

```
x = "a" ~CharacterRange~ "z" ~RandomChoice~ 1*^6;

Do[x[[s]], {s, spans}]      // AccurateTiming
Do[Query[s][x], {s, spans}] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.0106673
>
> 3.594706
> ```

Alright, that seems to account for some of the difference as `Part` is only 337 times faster than `Query` here, but that is still a huge difference.
The reason I was interested in `Query` is that by default it will not fail on out-of-bounds span ranges as `Part` will:

```
a = Range[9];

a[[5 ;; 11]]

Query[5 ;; 11][a]
```

> Part::take: Cannot take positions 5 through 11 in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. >>
>
> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}[[5 ;; 11]]
>
> {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

It also returns a `Missing` expression for a single part that is out-of-bounds:

```
Query[12][Range@9]
```

> ```
> Missing["PartAbsent", 12]
> ```

This feature is controlled by [`PartBehavior`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PartBehavior.html).  Perhaps its overhead is high so let's turn it off and try again:

```
SetOptions[Query, PartBehavior -> None];
Do[Query[s][x], {s, spans}] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 3.568204
> ```

Well that doesn't seem to be the case.  Thankfully Szabolcs's post in [Why is Dataset upset by division by zero?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56605/why-is-dataset-upset-by-division-by-zero/56608#56608) made me take a look at the other options for `Query`.  With [`MissingBehavior`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MissingBehavior.html) set to `Automatic` `Query` will apply special rules for certain operators when there are `Missing[]` expressions:

```
Query[Total] @ {1, 2, 3, Missing[]}
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

This should have no role for `Span` however:

```
Query[2 ;; 4] @ {1, 2, 3, Missing[]}
```

> ```
> {2, 3, Missing[]}
> ```

Let's turn it off and time again just to be sure:

```
SetOptions[Query, MissingBehavior -> None];
Do[Query[s][x], {s, spans}] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.355520
> ```

It seems we have found the cause of most of the slow-down, yet it makes no sense to me for this to have any effect as there is no special behavior to apply for `Missing` elements in a `Span` operation.

With `FailureAction -> None` this comes down to `0.285016` second, or ~27 times slower than `Part` on unpacked data.

#### Questions

1. Why would `MissingBehavior` affect the speed of a `Span` operation?
2. Why is `Query` still many times slower than `Part`, even with all special handling turned off?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's start by taking a look at the compiled form of one of our queries:

```
Dataset`CompileQuery[Query @ First @ spans]

(* Dataset`WithOverrides@*Checked[Slice[205 ;; 313], Identity] *)
```

We can see that the operation is not implemented directly in terms of part.  Indeed, there are three components: `` Dataset`WithOverrides ``, `` GeneralUtilities`Checked `` and `` GeneralUtilities`Slice ``.

`` Dataset`WithOverrides `` is an elaborate function that implements `MissingBehaviour`.  A quick peek at the output of `` ??Dataset`WithOverrides `` shows that it scans its input ten times, each time looking for some kind of missing data.  It handles all possible cases, whether they involve associations, lists, sequences, etc.  There is some scope for improvement in this function.  For example, it could check the cases in one pass instead of ten.  However, there are a lot of rules to check and so long as they are expressed using pattern-matching, this function is going to remain costly.  This function is responsible for all but a few percent of the total runtime.  Fortunately, it can be disabled using `MissingBehaviour -> None` as observed in the question:

```
Dataset`CompileQuery[Query[First @ spans, MissingBehavior -> None]]

(* Checked[Slice[205 ;; 313], Identity] *)
```

This brings us to `` GeneralUtilities`Checked ``.  Its role is to implement `FailureAction`.  `??` shows us that this function is nowhere near as elaborate as `` Dataset`WithOverrides ``, but it still represents some overhead.  Again, it can be turned off:

```
Dataset`CompileQuery[Query[First @ spans, MissingBehavior->None, FailureAction->None]]

(* Slice[205;;313] *)
```

Finally, we are left with `` GeneralUtilities`Slice ``.  Presumably this function is being used instead of `Part` on account of part syntax within the context of `Query` being more general.  More spelunking commands can give us some insight:

```
??GeneralUtilities`Slice

??GeneralUtilities`Slice`PackagePrivate`slice

??GeneralUtilities`Slice`PackagePrivate`part
```

Following the observed theme, we see that these functions are very elaborate and general.  They need to handle any possible type of input, not just the lists that we feed them in this example.

**Taking Stock**

The recurring pattern we see in these query components is that they must deal with very general cases.  As it stands, the query compiler has no idea what kind of operand is going to be passed to `Query`.  It could receive any arbitrary nesting of datasets, associations, lists and general expressions.  Therefore, the so-called "compiled" form is really an interpreter.  To be truly compiled, there would need to be more type information available up front.

For example, if the `` TypeSystem` `` type were known ahead of time, our final compiled query expression could use `Part` directly (possibly with an optional light wrapper to verify that the passed operand conforms to the predeclared type).

A further complication for queries is that in general they have parameters other than the queried object.  In our case, the slice specification is different for each query.  Ideally, we would be able to describe the types of such parameters to the compiler rather than having to pass values explicitly.  In the case at hand, this would mean that we would only have to incur the overhead of compiling the query once, instead of compiling it once per slice.

Perhaps we will see such enhanced query compilation capabilities in a future release if WL starts to drift towards being a hybrid early/late binding language like Lisp.  But until then, we must "compile by hand" as necessary.

---

**Update**

The assertion above that `` Dataset`WithOverrides `` scans its input multiple times is incorrect.  In fact, the scans are used to monkey-patch many system functions.  These patches implement the `MissingBehavior` functionality, but they also have the potential to disturb the normal operation of those functions outside of the query machinery.  For an example of such unexpected behaviour, see [Possible Bug in ProbitModelFit when used in a Dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57737/142).

Comment: Great answer. :)

Comment: I added an update to correct a wrong assertion about the scans in ``Dataset`WithOverrides``.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer. It is just a very long comment.

Both a simple manually operated drill press and a computer-controlled five-axis omni-mill can drill a hole through a piece of bar stock. And both will do the actual drilling in about the same amount of time. If one hole in one bar is all you want, then you will accomplish the job much faster with the old-fashioned drill press, because the set-up time on the omni-mill will totally overwhelm the actual drilling operation.

Is the foregoing analogy applicable to the matter brought up in this question? I don't  know, but it might be. Could it be that before it can apply optimized, low-level code to actually do the job, `Query` has a lot of high-level (slow) code to run to figure out what it has been asked to do?

`Query` is a brand-new and very complex function. Perhaps we shouldn't be surprised that `Query 1.0` is slow. I predict it will speed up in future releases as the developers refine it.

The documentation for `Query` is interesting in that it starts with only one usage message:

> Query[operator-1, operator-2, ....] represents a query that can be applied to a Dataset object, in which the successive operator-i are applied at successively deeper levels.

It then, in a seeming contradiction, goes on to give many examples of `Query` applied to associations rather than to datasets. Still, I believe the initial usage message holds a real truth; WRI implemented `Query` as a five-axis omni-mill to do fancy machining on datasets.

Comment: could it be that querry is a O(n) algorithm where part is  O(1) algorithm. Because the name implies that querry must scan the elements for testing. Sure it should optimize for set reductions but it does not do so yet. just speculating.

Comment: @joojaa. I think it's been established that `Part` is O(1) and you may be right about `Query` being O(n). However, I also think `Query` might also have a very high set-up cost. Like you, just speculating.