# Possible Bug in ProbitModelFit when used in a Dataset

Tags: bugs, dataset

Since upgrading to *Mathematica 10* on Mac OSX I have come across a number of instances of this error, which occurs using Probit and Logit model fit.

[image]

A bit of googling show this is something to do with [the estimation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares).

But the issue is more complex. When I estimate the model straight from this dataset I get the error, but when I first take the values of the data, then fit the model, I get the expected result.

Here's an example

```
var = {age, gender, photo6};

mTest = SemanticImport[
   "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3997716/test.csv"];

testFit = 
 mTest[ProbitModelFit[#, var, 
    var] &, {#age, #gender, #photo6, #rawM} &]

testFit2 = 
 ProbitModelFit[#, var, 
    var] &@(mTest[All, {"age", "gender", "photo6", "rawM"}] // 
     Normal // Values)
```

Output of this is

[image]

Why the two different results for the same calculation? Is there a workaround that allows the estimation to proceed when directly using the dataset?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I thought so too. I suspect it is a general bug in the GeneralizedLinearModelFit algorithm because I've never even seen the error before (prior to V10) and now it is popping up in a couple of other places as well (though I don't have a small working example handy).

Comment: You are using `SemanticImport`, which is new to V10. Could the problem lie there? How did you import your data in earlier versions of _Mathematica_?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I don't think it has anything to do with `SemanticImport`. You can try importing the data with `Import` and create the `Dataset` yourself, the error still persists whereas `LinearModelFit` works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug.  The rest of this response speculates as to the possible cause.

We start by observing that the test can be made to work by suppressing `MissingBehaviour`:

```
mTest[
  ProbitModelFit[#, var, var] &
, {#age, #gender, #photo6, #rawM} &
, MissingBehavior -> None
]
```

[image: result screenshot]

It also works if `FailureAction -> None` is specified instead, but then the exhibited error message about non-real values is produced (along with the correct result).

As [noted elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57093/142) `MissingBehavior` is implemented by `` Dataset`WithOverrides ``.  `` ??Dataset`WithOverrides `` reveals that this function temporarily alters the definitions of a number of symbols, namely those in this list:

```
Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$AllChangedSymbols

(* { Commonest,First,InterquartileRange,Kurtosis,Last,Mean,Median,Missing,Most,
     Quartiles,Rest,RootMeanSquare,Skewness,StandardDeviation,Total,Variance }
*)
```

It so happens that `ProbitModelFit` uses `Total`.  We can verify that fact like this:

```
$data = mTest[All, {#age, #gender, #photo6, #rawM} &];

On @@ Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$AllChangedSymbols

ProbitModelFit[$data // Normal, {age, gender, photo6}, {age, gender, photo6}]

Off[]

(* ... produces many trace messages containing Total ... *)
```

It would appear that the patching performed by `` Dataset`WithOverrides `` is interfering with the operation of `ProbitModelFit`.  We can simulate this by engaging in some patching of our own:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Total}
, Unprotect @ Total
; Total[n___] /; False := Null
; ProbitModelFit[$data // Normal,{age,gender,photo6},{age,gender,photo6}]
]
```

[image: result screenshot]

This patch is even less invasive than the one installed by `` Dataset`WithOverrides ``, and yet it generates the same error message (and the same correct output).  It would seem that `ProbitModelFit` is expecting `Total` to operate exactly as it is shipped -- nothing more, nothing less.

**Conclusion**

`ProbitModelFit` does not function properly within a query with default missing- and failure-handling.  The missing-handling alters the definition of `Total` in a manner that causes `ProbitModelFit` to issue a warning message.  The failure-handling sees that message and, by default, fails the whole query operation.  Correct operation can be restored by either disabling the missing-handling, the failure-handling, or both.

The missing-handling is implemented by monkey-patching various low-level system components.  This patching implements the proper `Query` semantics, at the cost of disturbing normal non-query system behaviour.  Such disturbances are a frequent consequence of monkey-patching.  The patching methodology explains not only the issue under discussion, but a number of other erratic `Dataset` behaviours logged on this site.

Comment: That's a brilliant answer! Your `MissingBehavior` workaround will suit my needs for now.