# Query/Part Bug with :>

Tags: associations

**Bug observed in 10.0.1 and persisting through to 10.4.0**

`Part` can fail with `:>`

```
 d = <|"a" :> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|> |>|>;

 d[["a", "b", All]]

 (* 
    Part::pspec1: Part specification b is not applicable. >>

    Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"]

  *)
```

something `Query` seems immune to  ...

```
     d // Query["a", "b", All]

  (* <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>  *)
```

... well almost

```
 {"a" :> 1} // Query["a"]

 (* Missing["PartInvalid", "a"] *)
```

Confirmed Bugs?

Comment: This question admittedly veers towards closability by essentially combining a bug report with a "meta" proposal about their more systematic resolution. On the other hand, I've included the above two bugs since I spent more time tracking them down than someone might care to repeat given their pretty basic nature (and therefore disguisability).

Comment: I am honestly not sure what your question is, but from what I gather, I suspect that your issue might be more appropriate for the Meta site.

Comment: This is not a well-posed question. It should be broken up in a question about a possible bug in associations and a meta-question about tag management.

Comment: @m_goldberg. Agreed. Suspected Bug confirmed by Tech support. Will tag as such with a seconder.

Comment: Bug also present in 10.1.0.  Perhaps related: [(59979)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59979/121)

Comment: I observe exactly the same behaviour as in the question with version 10.0.1.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at this again I think it is not a bug but a design limitation.  Despite the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) appearing similar an `Association` is not *actually* an atomic Association object until it is evaluated.  Take for example:

```
AtomQ[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4|>]    (* True *)

AtomQ[Unevaluated[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>]]       (* False *)
```

One may substitute `AssociationQ` for `AtomQ` with the same result.

Note that `Unevaluated` does not prevent an Integer from being recognized as atomic:

```
AtomQ[Unevaluated[2]]  (* True *)
```

Given this if use of `:>` prevents evaluation, as I believe it does and should, the expression `<|"b" -> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|> |>` in your example *is not an actual Association object* until it is evaluated, therefore e.g. `Part` (which is [simpler by far](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56609/121) than `Query`) sees no deeper Keys to extract.  However if we let it pull the Value of `"a"`, which causes it to evaluate, we can extract the Key `"b"` without issue:

```
d = <|"a" :> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>|>|>;

d[["a"]][["b"]]
```

> ```
> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>
> ```

```
d[["a"]][["b", "c"]]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

I feel the issue is similar to this:

```
Cases["a" -> 1/2, _Rational]
Cases["b" :> 1/2, _Rational]
```

> ```
> {1/2}
>
> {}
> ```

```
Cases["a" -> 3 I, _Complex]
Cases["b" :> 3 I, _Complex]
```

> ```
> {3 I}
>
> {}
> ```

i.e. `1/2` and `3 I` are not `Rational` or `Complex` until released for evaluation.

---

Regarding the final example `{"a" :> 1} // Query["a"]` I think that may be considered a bug as if `Query` works with simple `Rule` lists I think it should work here too.

Comment: Hmm ... How does this fit in with the following? `d2 = <|"a" -> <|"b" :> <|"c" -> <|"d" :> "e"|>|>|>|>;`
`d2[["a"]]`
`d2[["a", "b", All]]`
`d2[["a", "b", "c"]]`

Comment: @Ronald I don't think it does, meaning I got it wrong or at least incomplete. :-(  I shall return to this later today and see if I can find any logic to it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems to be a bug firstly because different output comes from different ways of specifying a `Part`

```
d = <|"a" -> <|"b" :> <|"c" -> <|"d" :> "e"|>|>|>|>;

d[["a", "b", All]]    (* <|"c" -> <|"d" :> "e"|>|> *)
d[["a", "b", 1]]      (* "c" -> <|"d" :> "e"|> *)
d[["a", "b", "c"]]    (* Missing["KeyAbsent", "b"]  *)
```

Mr Wizard's answer speculated that the cause of this might be due to when/how an `Association` is interpreted (or loses it atomicity) and while the above example tends to suggest otherwise, his reasoning might go some way to explaining the bug's origin. Certainly it appears as if some initial "whole processing" is taking place as (opposed the sequential `d[["a"]][["b"]]`) as the following analysis shows (and without being privy to the no-doubt many (competing) imperatives of `Cases`, `Part`, `Query` etc). Firstly, it seems to me that the example,

```
Cases["a" :> 3 I, _Complex]  (* {} *) 

(* anomalously IMO - {3 I} is more natural *)
```

*should* instead yield `{3 I}` (as should also `Cases["a":>3 I, 3 I]`) since it's more analogous to the second expression of the following as opposed to the fourth (since the number's `Complex` nature is a parsing issue more than an evaluative one).

```
Cases["b" -> 1, _Integer]   (* {1} *)
Cases["b" :> 1, _Integer]   (* {1} *)
t = 1;
Cases["b" -> 1, _Integer]   (* {1} *)
Cases["b" :> t, _Integer]   (*  {}  *)
```

Compare the last evaluation with

```
Cases["a" :> 3 I, _?NumberQ]    (* {3 I}  *)
Cases["b" :> t, _?IntegerQ]     (* {1}  *)
```

which are both expected since now each part gets evaluated in the test. Hence `Cases` respects the evaluation instruction in `->, :>` while looking at an expression's structure only overiding this when explicitly asked to do so (such as in a test). Similarly, `Part` respects `->, :>` evaluation instruction when looking at an `Association`'s structure

```
t = <|"b" -> 1|>;

D1 = <|"a" -> t|>;
D2 = <|"a" :> t|>;

D1[["a", "b"]]   (* 1 *)
D2[["a", "b"]]   (* Missing["KeyAbsent","a"] *)
```

`Query` however, will overide `:>`'s delayed-evaluation to avoid not finding anything

```
D1 // Query["a", "b"]  (* 1 *) 
D2 // Query["a", "b"]  (* 1 *)
```

Sometimes this can lead to apparently anomalous, but probably, ultimately useful behaviour

```
s[2] = <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> 3|>;

D3 = <|"a" -> s[2]|>;
D4 = <|"a" :> s[2]|>;

D3[["a", 1]]   (* 1 *)
D3[["a", 2]]   (* 3 *)

D4[["a", 1]]   (* 2 *)
D4[["a", 2]]   (* Missing["KeyAbsent","a"] *)
D4 // Query["a", 1]   (* 2 *)  (* not 1 as might be expected as per below  *)
D4 // Query["a", 2]   (* 3 *)  (* apparently anomalous but probably useful *)
```

When it comes to more deeply nested associations, `Part` allows this  `:>` evaluative instruction to (IMO anomalously) obscure the initial structure provided

```
D5 = <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1|>|>;
D6 = <|"a" :> <|"b" -> 1|>|>;
D5[["a", "b"]]   (* 1 *)
D6[["a", "b"]]   (* Missing["KeyAbsent","a"] *) (* anomolously IMO - 1 is more natural *)
```

unlike `Query` which as per its usual earnest self invariably pulls out all stops (or at least parts)

```
D5 // Query["a", "b"]  (* 1 *)
D6 // Query["a", "b"]  (* 1 *)
```

In other words, to remove these claimed anomalies with deeply nested `Association`s, two `Association`s that are identical modulo `Rule`, `RuleDelayed` (both in unevaluated an evaluated forms) need to have the same output when `Part` operates on them - an eventuality guaranteed with Unit Tests satisfing this condition doubling up with `Rule`s replaced with `RuleDelayed`s.

N.B. The other observed behaviour/formatting anomalies seem more clearcut

```
{"a" -> 1} // Query["a"]  (* 1 *)
{"a" :> 1} // Query["a"]  (* Missing["PartInvalid", "a"] *)

<|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1|>|>    (* <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1|>|> *)
<|"a" :> <|"b" -> 1|>|>    (* <|"a" :> Association["b" -> 1]|> *)
```