# How to handle Part function error when position does not exist?

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

Say a list `list={{1,2},{3,4}}`, `list[[1]]` and `list[[2]]` works. But `list[[3]]` gives an error of

> Part::partw: Part 3 of {{1,2},{3,4}} does not exist.

This is alright, since there's no part 3 indeed. But what if I wish to handle that error. So in this case, I want to return empty list `{}` if the part-does-not-exist error happens.

I try to refer to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html, but it seems to be involved with `Throw`. Therefore I try to think of a simpler scenario as above.

Comment: Have you seen `Indexed[]`?

Comment: `Indexed[list,3]` would also give error.

Comment: +1 for it's a good mentioning.

Comment: Related: [(14645)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with the essence of @Nasser's answer, I go with a simplified version for now.

```
Quiet[Check[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}[[3]], {}], Part::partw]
```

This returns empty list if partw message happens.

Answer (score 6):

> But what if I wish to handle that error. So in this case, I want to
>   return empty list {} if the part-does-not-exist error happens

One possibility might be

```
ClearAll[process];

process[lis_List, (n_Integer)?Positive] := Module[{},
       Quiet@Check[lis[[n]], {}, Part::partw]
]
```

Or just

```
process[lis_List, (n_Integer)?Positive] := Quiet@Check[lis[[n]], {}, Part::partw]
```

And now

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
process[list, 2]
 (*{3, 4}*)
```

and

```
process[list, 3]
(* {} *)
```

`Quiet` can be removed if you want to hear the beep and see the error message on console.

Answer (score 4):

Without using `Quiet` or `Check` you can use

```
SafePart[expr_, n_Integer?Positive, default_ : $Failed] := 
  If[Length[expr] >= n, Part[expr, n], default];
SafePart[expr_, parts : {__Integer?Positive}, default_ : $Failed] := 
 Fold[SafePart[#1, #2, default] &, expr, parts]
```

then you have

```
SafePart[{{{a, b}, {c}}}, {1, 2, 1}]
(* c *)

SafePart[{{{a, b}, {c}}}, 3, {}]
(* {} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)?  Default behavior:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Query[3][list]
```

> ```
> Missing["PartAbsent", 3]
> ```

Somewhat customized:

```
fn = Replace[Missing["PartAbsent", _] -> {}];

Query[3, fn][list]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Or *with care*:

```
Unprotect[Missing];
Missing["PartAbsent", _] = {};
Protect[Missing];

Query[3][list]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Caveat, `Query` can be slow:

- [Why is Query so much slower than Part?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56609/121)